# How to do multiple array_slice on a lengthy array?

Tags: php, slice

I am very new to php.  I am trying to do multiple array slices on a large array.  Right now this is a section of my code:

```
$row1 = array_slice($filtered, 0, 22);
$row2 = array_slice($filtered, 22, 22);
$row3 = array_slice($filtered, 44, 22);
$row5 = array_slice($filtered, 66, 22);
$row6 = array_slice($filtered, 88, 22);
$row7 = array_slice($filtered, 110, 22);
$row8 = array_slice($filtered, 132, 22);
$row9 = array_slice($filtered, 154, 22);
$row10 = array_slice($filtered, 176, 22);
```

Each time the starting position of the array slice is 22 more than the previous row.  Instead of writing out all of these rows (674 total) is there a statement that I can use to automatically advance the starting position 22 until it reaches an end, as well as assigning it to a variable that increases by 1 each time like the example. Thanks.

Comment: Arrays and `for`/`while` loops will do wonders for you.

Answer (score 5):

You could use the php [array_chunk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) function to split the original array into blocks of any size

i.e. `$rows = array_chunk($filtered, 22);`

Answer (score 0):

```
$previous = 0;
$current = 22;
$rows = array();

for ($current; $current < size($filtered); $current+22) {
    $rows[] = array_slice($filtered, $previous, $current);
    $previous = $current;
}
```

You'll need a special case for when the `$filtered` array count is not divisible by 22.

Answer (score 0):

Use [array_chunk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) and then [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

```
$j = 1;
foreach( array_chunk($list, 22)  as $chunk){
    ${"row{$j}"} = $chunk;
    $j++;
}
```